# Web Language Execution

Tags: javascript, browser, compilation, dart, virtual-machine

TL;DR:
How does JavaScript code embedded in a website become CPU instructions executed on real hardware.
Same thing for Dart.

Hi,
I'm struggling to fully understand the modern web language buzz word djungle.
Basically my map of how ("higher level") programming language were brought
to execution consisted of the concepts of C and Java translation.

The C compiler takes C text as input and generates binary machine code but
can internally be thought of as front and back end, where the front end
transforms C text into some IR and the back end takes that IR and generates
the platform dependent machine code.
Using Java the same split is more visible because the Java compiler transforms
Java text into Java bytecode (IR) which is then JITed/interpreted by
the JVM which does the actual transform from bytecode to platform dependet
machine instructions.

So far in my mind the only real difference was that the IR step was sort of
exposed in the Java world, because one could target the JVM with whatever
frontend (e.g. Scala) where when using, say the gcc, this whole IR thing
was hidden away.

Then someone pointed me to Clang, which compiles C to LLVM which
in my mind is just exposing that split between front end and back end.

So now there is JavaScript. As far as I can workout there is something
called a JavaScript "engine", like Google V8. What this thing does is
it takes JS text and "compiles" it to platform dependent machine code
at runtime, all in memory. I imagine it as putting the end result
(instructions) some where in the process mem and then jumping to it.
Is this correct or did I get it wrong? Because sometimes one can read
about JS VMs in the browser...

Then there is Dart which got both: a DartVM (stand alone as well as embedded
in the browser) but also the option of generating machine code directly
or at least at the Dart web site there is an article which explains why
they decided against a byte code VM.
But is it still a (software) VM if there's no IR? Or if there's a IR, 
what is it?

Right now I'm not able to map these "explanations" from the project websites
to my current understanding of how languages go from text to
execution.

Thanks for any clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer I would say JavaScript and Dart are very similar to Java in this regard with the difference that the former do not distinguish between source code and byte code. The source code fulfills both functions.
I'm no experte in these things but in my understanding a VM in this context is a program that takes source code of some language as input and generates executable CPU instructions and let the CPU execute the instructions.
Whether this is jitted or interpreted or a bit of both is an implementation detail.

**EDIT**
I expected you want to know more details but StackOverflow is the wrong place. This question is just to broad. In more frequented tags this question would already have been closed. A computer science study would be more appropriate place.

Anyways - to your comment: I don't think they do the opposite. They take the source a programmer wrote and generate something a CPU can process. What differs is where each step is done and how fine/coarse-grainded the steps are. Storing on disk or in RAM is not that much different (think of swap space on disk). It's just about delivering to the client and then "compile" or compile and then deliver to the client or about deliver to the client to allow it to execute offline or require to download each time before execution with the advantage that the client always get's the most recent version without any deployment hassles.

The reason it is delivered in source code and interpreted/compiled on the client is that it is considered one of the success factors of web applications that the source code is available for everyone. Minification makes the source almost as unreadable as compiling but somehow it inspired the open source world nevertheless. Companies/people designing new web languages fear that without this "feature" their baby might not fly.

LLVM in the browser is for people who consider compiled code as more advantageous.

You can't expect that things are the way they are because it's the only reasonable way to do them.
What we have today is thousendfold tweaked existing technologies combined with a lot of sad and/or lucky accidents.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I gotta be honest: It leaves me still unsatisfied like all the abstract talk on the web. How can they be "very similar" if they do something completely opposite? Java can save the compilation result on disk, even ship it pre-compiled using jar files. Why do we send the original source embedded in the website and don't send only byte code/pre-compilled code? Does it really happen in-memory? Why do they provide "virtual machines" and not compilers if they map straight to machine code? ...

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Gunter is a saint for answering this question so extendedly.  As he said, it's really too broad for Stack Overflow.  I suggest you read an article on the term Virtual Machine and if you're really interested take an introductory course/read an introductory book on computer science.

Comment: My bad. I thought "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers". Next time I'll ask what a Constructor does or when one would need virtual Destructors because that stuff is nowhere on the web... Anyway, thanks Günter!

Comment: The help menu contains information about asking good questions. I forgot to mention that VMs main purpose is to abstract hardware differences away.

Comment: I found what I was looking for. The "JIT Compilation" section of: https://blog.mozilla.org/luke/2014/01/14/asm-js-aot-compilation-and-startup-performance/